# Second check of radio button not showing up

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have radio buttons that are checked if you click a div. The problem is that the radio button does not get 'visually checked' again if you change your mind and click back on the original radio button.

The attribute of the radio button 'checked' is added/removed via if/else statements.

```
$('.donate-now .radio--container:nth-child(1)').click(function(){

    if($('#answer2').attr('checked')){
          $('#answer2').removeAttr("checked");
          $('#answer1').attr('checked', 'checked');
     }
     else{
          $('#answer1').attr('checked', 'checked');
     }
 });

$('.donate-now .radio--container:nth-child(2)').click(function(){

    if($('#answer1').attr('checked')){
       $('#answer1').removeAttr("checked");
       $('#answer2').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    else{
       $('#answer2').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Please see my codepen for full working example
https://codepen.io/erayner/pen/dwqXdx

Comment: Given that the radio buttons have the same name, your logic appears to be doing more work than is necessary.  All you have to do on container click is set the child radio button to checked true.  It will auto uncheck the other.

Answer (score 1):

You really only need to check the nested radio.  Since they have the same name, it will uncheck the other radio.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.donate-now .radio--container').on('click', function() {
    // find the nested radio button, and set it to checked
    $(this).find('input[name="choice"]').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.radio--container:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.radio--container:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.donate-now {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.input--container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#submitBtn {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>WHO GETS YOUR VOTE?</h1>
  </div>


  <form action="thankyou.html" method="post">
    <div class="donate-now">
      <div class="radio--container">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
        <h2>CAT1</h2>
        <p>Vote Cat<br />Vote Cat1</p>
        <div class="input--container"><input type="radio" id="answer1" name="choice" /><label for='answer1' id='label1'>Vote</label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="radio--container">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
        <h2>CAT2</h2>
        <p>Vote Cat<br />Vote CAT2</p>
        <div class="input--container"><input type="radio" id="answer2" name="choice" /><label for='answer2' id='label2'>Vote</label></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Vote now">
  </form>
</div>
```